# Java Concurrent Socket Programming

Tags: java, concurrency, distributed-computing

Below is my code for a simple Concurrent Server. Whenever I run multiple clients, the server only prints out the input of the first client. I'm  not sure what I've done wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8001);
        while (true){
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println(clientSocket);
            ConcurrentServer client = new ConcurrentServer(clientSocket);
            client.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException i){}
}

public void run(){
    try {
        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(concurrentSocket.getInputStream()));
        outputStream = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(concurrentSocket.getOutputStream()));

        String testString = inputStream.readLine();
        System.out.println(testString);


    } catch (IOException i){}
}
```

Comment: `ConcurrentServer extends Thread` I presume?

Comment: `} catch (IOException i){}`. It's very, very likely that your problem is because you **ignore** the error Java is trying to give you.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, it is obvious that ommiting exception here is made for code redabilty. Otherwise, lets mention here about logging exception, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code might help you to understand how to run multiple clients concurrently. :)

**What this code does?** *TCP Client sends a string to the server and TCP server sends back the string in UPPERCASE format & the server can do this concurrently with multiple connections.*

I have **included 3** files for the server and one more for testing the **server with multiple clients**(ClientTest.java)

**Main.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Server(3000).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Server.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server {

    private ServerSocket sSocket;
    private boolean run;
    private int port;

    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
        this.port = port;
        this.sSocket = new ServerSocket(this.port);
    }

    public void start() {

        this.run = true;
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).info("Server is listening on port: " + port);

        try {
            while (run) {
                Socket cs = sSocket.accept();
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName())
                        .info("New Client Connected! " + cs.getPort());
                new Thread(new Client(cs)).start(); // Put to a new thread.
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).severe(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.run = false;
    }
}
```

**Client.java** (Client Process on server)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Client implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;

    private DataOutputStream out; // write for the client
    private BufferedReader in; // read from the client

    public Client(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do client process
        outToClient(inFromClient().toUpperCase());
        closeConnection();
    }

    private String inFromClient() {

        String messageFromClient = "";

        /*
         *  Do not use try with resources because once -
         *  - it exits the block it will close your client socket too.
         */
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            messageFromClient = in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).severe("InFromClientErr - " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return messageFromClient.trim().equals("") ? "No Inputs given!" : messageFromClient;
    }

    private void outToClient(String message) {
        try {
            out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeBytes(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).severe("OutToClientErr - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void closeConnection() {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).severe(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**ClientTest.java** (For Testing clients)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClientTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Socket clientSocket;

        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 3000);

            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            outToServer.writeBytes(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine() + '\n'); // Get user input and send.
            System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine()); // Print the server response.

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue was instead with the client. Not the server. The socket was declared outside of the for loop, and therefore only one connection was being created. Like so below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8001);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            System.out.println("Starting client: " + i);
            ConcurrentClient concurrentClient = new ConcurrentClient(socket, i);
            concurrentClient.run();
        }
    } catch (IOException io) {
    }
}
```

The Socket should be declared inside the for loop like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8001);
            System.out.println("Starting client: " + i);
            ConcurrentClient concurrentClient = new ConcurrentClient(socket, i);
            concurrentClient.run();
        }
    } catch (IOException io) {
    }
}
```

Comment: `} catch (IOException io) {}` - you really are a fan of swallowing exceptions. Please, please break this habit.

Comment: No, you don't need to create multiple Sockets. You code from the question was right.
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8001);
        while (true){
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
 serverSocket.accept(); will wait until a new connection will be made.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()

Comment: @DmitriiCheremisin you're misreading - this is the _client_ code.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes normally I would but because I was rushing I neglected exception handling.

Comment: @DmitriiCheremisin Yes what you are saying is correct. However, the updated code is on the client, not the server. The server code has remained the same. I am using thread to create multiple clients as well.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but there is **never** an excuse for this code. Not when you are in a rush, not when you are "just trying something out". **never**.

Comment: Thank you both for your help.

Comment: @BoristheSpider What?! It is clearly written that "Below is my code for a simple Concurrent Server." Server, not client! Where do you find word client?
Next phrase " Whenever I run multiple clients, the server only prints out the input of the first client." It is obvious that he writes about server!
Client may be telnet or something like it for testing.

Comment: @DmitriiCheremisin "_The issue was instead with the client. Not the server_". This is code for the client.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, don't you see that he provided solution to his own question and made it the same time, when I posted my answer??! This text from his own solution, but original question was with words "Below is my code for a simple Concurrent Server". Please, read carefully next time before commenting!

Answer (score -2):

I really don't know why you need so complex structure of input and output streams. It is better to use Scanner that will wait for the new input.
Also you can use PrintWriter to output the results of your conversation.

Here is server that accepts multiple clients:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConcurrentServer extends Thread {
private Socket concurrentSocket;

public ConcurrentServer(Socket clientSocket) {
    this.concurrentSocket = clientSocket;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8001);
        while (true){
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println(clientSocket);
            ConcurrentServer client = new ConcurrentServer(clientSocket);
            client.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException i){}
}

public void run(){
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = concurrentSocket.getInputStream();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
        OutputStream outputStream = concurrentSocket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outputStream);

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            pw.println("message: " + line);
            pw.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException i){}
}
```

}

Comment: This is random guesswork - you didn't diagnose the problem so you posted random "working" code. This is not how we answer questions on SO.

Comment: @BoristheSpider What is your solution?? I tried to help him and posted working code with comments on the wrong places. Did you notice "I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Any help would be appreciated." ??

Comment: You didn't diagnose the problem. You didn't provide a solution. I didn't post a solution because I could not diagnose the problem. As it turns out the problem was in unrelated client code - not in the posted code. This is why we comment, ask questions, spend time understanding the problem. I stand by my comment - this is not an answer, as you cannot answer without understanding what the real question was.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, you are not willing to help. If you are not - it is better to stay calm. As you may see, the author accepted particullary the same solution as my.